# Good practice to return DateTime from PHP to JS

Tags: javascript, php, datetime

I've created file api.php

```
<?php
// Prevent caching.
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');

// The JSON standard MIME header.
header('Content-type: application/json');   

//mssql_select_db("**", mssql_connect(**));
$conn=mssql_connect(***);    

$query = "SELECT ROUND([AirTemp_C],1) as [T]
                ,[DT]
            FROM [ASUTP].[dbo].[Temperature_ER]
            WHERE [Place] = 'ER06' AND [DT] > '26.05.2015 11:00'";

$qwr_res = mssql_query($query);

while ($row=mssql_fetch_array($qwr_res))
{
    $temps[] = array (
        'x' => $row['DT'],
        'y' => $row['T']
                );
}
echo json_encode($temps);   
?>
```

It returns JSON like [{"x":"2015-05-26 11:02:04","y":26.3}] with my measurments.

I want to use this data to draw graph using canvasjs-1.6.2. Here is my code:
window.onload = function () {

```
    $.getJSON("api.php",function(data1)
                        {                               
                            var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",
                            {

                                title:{
                                    text: "Title",
                                    fontSize: 30
                                },
                                animationEnabled: true,
                                zoomEnabled:true,
                                height: 500,
                                axisX:{

                                    gridColor: "Silver",
                                    tickColor: "silver",
                                    labelAngle: -80,
                                    valueFormatString: "DD.MM HH:mm"

                                },                        
                                            toolTip:{
                                            shared:true
                                            },
                                theme: "theme2",
                                axisY: {
                                    gridColor: "Silver",
                                    tickColor: "silver"
                                },
                                legend:{
                                    verticalAlign: "center",
                                    horizontalAlign: "right"
                                },
                                data: [
                                {        
                                    type: "line",
                                    showInLegend: true,
                                    lineThickness: 2,
                                    name: "T",
                                    //markerType: "square",
                                    color: "#F08080",
                                    dataPoints: data1
                                }
                                ],
                            legend:{
                                cursor:"pointer",
                                itemclick:function(e){
                                if (typeof(e.dataSeries.visible) === "undefined" || e.dataSeries.visible) {
                                    e.dataSeries.visible = false;
                                }
                                else{
                                    e.dataSeries.visible = true;
                                }
                                chart.render();
                                }
                            }
                            });

                            chart.render();
                        });
```

But it seems that this chart (or JS at all) cant use my Date value as a correct DateTime so chart can't render.

I've fixed this issue with such loop:

```
for(var i=0;i<data1.length;i++)
{
   data1[i].x = new Date(data1[i].x);
}
```

I should notice that I'm using PHP 5.2 and I'm not allowed to upgrade it.
So my questions are:

1. Is my way to get data for chart via api.php correct?
2. Is there a way to pass correct DateTime values from php to JS without that loop convert?

Comment: Due to how different browsers parse string dates differently, I prefer to pass dates as unix timestamps for simplicity.

Comment: Can you show me the right way? Also I'm heavily restricted to support IE 6.0 beacause it's our corporative rules and most users have IE 7/8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in comments, the most reliable cross-browser way to transfer dates is using a time value. UNIX time values are in seconds since 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z. Javascript time values are from the same epoch, but use milliseconds so you just multiply UNIX time values by 1000 and pass directly to the Date constructor.

So the JSON might be like:

```
'[{x:"1432788147300", y:26.3}]'
```

and if the *x* value is read into a variable called *unixTimeValue*, the code would be like:

```
var javascriptDate = new Date(unixTimeValue * 1000);
```

However, if you can't do that, you can parse strings like '2015-05-26 11:02:04' fairly easily. Assuming that the date is UTC, you can use [*Date.UTC*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.4.3) to convert it to a date object:

```
function parseISOUTC(s) {
  var b = s.split(/\D/);
  return new Date(Date.UTC(b[0],b[1],b[2],b[3],b[4],b[5]));
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that helped a lot. And what about my approach with getting data, is it correct to get data this way?