# Loading PHP Variable Into A Javascript Variable

Tags: javascript, php, json, youtube-api

I'm building a batabase driven website which uses Javascript to play videos on my website using the YouTube API, but I can't load in the data I have extracted via PHP into the Javascript player.

My table is (Example codes only):

```
ID | One | Two
---------------
01 | 832 | 943
```

Here's the PHP code I use to get the data:

```
<?php
$code_sql = "SELECT * FROM codes WHERE id = '$url_id'";
$code_res = mysqli_query($con, $code_sql);
while($code = mysqli_fetch_assoc($code_res)){

    $code_1 = $code["one"];
    $code_2 = $code["two"];

};
?>
```

And Here's the Javascript I'm trying to load it into:

```
var $vid1 = <?php echo json_encode("$code_1"); ?>;
var $vid2 = <?php echo json_encode("$code_2"); ?>;
var videoIDs = [
    '$vid1',
    '$vid2'
];
```

When I load the page it gives me a `Invalid Paramiters` in the video player. Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Comment: You're constantly overriding $code_1 and $code_2 in your php while loop, making them hold the last result only

Comment: And variables dont need to be in doublequotes `json_encode($code_1)`

Comment: @baao, cam you please explain what you mena by `overriding`? And how do I fix that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Good practice to return DateTime from PHP to JS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30496996/good-practice-to-return-datetime-from-php-to-js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove quotes from json_encode. Also remove single quote inside array

```
var $vid1 = <?php echo json_encode($code_1); ?>;
var $vid2 = <?php echo json_encode($code_2); ?>;
var videoIDs = [
    $vid1,
    $vid2
];
```

Comment: Thanks, but when I try this with quotes, it completely blocks out the video player. Any ideas why?

Comment: Remove double quotes from outside of php then try. See my edited answer